# Wordpress - Show all button in categories list

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-list-categories

I have this following page: http://webserver-meetandengage-com.m11e.net/insights/  and I'm using this code to list the categories in the yellow bar at the top:

```
<div class="container-fluid cat-list-container-fluid">
    <div class="container cat-list-container">

            <ul>
                <?php wp_list_categories( array(
                    'orderby'            => 'id',
                    'show_count'         => false,
                    'title_li' => false
                ) ); ?>
            </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have an ALL button at the start of the list that will show all categories again.

Is there an array option I can add to it and set it to True? or is there more to it? Any help would be greatly appriciated :)

Comment: Is there only one post type ? And can't you just add a link to <a href=" http://webserver-meetandengage-com.m11e.net/insights/ "> ALL </a>

Comment: _whoa_ all categories again? what does that mean?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for here.

Comment: Apologies, that what supposed to be show: Ive changed it now...

Comment: I could do Alex, but I wondered if there was a better, more correct way to do this, as the code is generating the menu... so adding a new list item at the beginning seems a bit clunky.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this was simply fixed by me using the show_option_all argument in the array like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid cat-list-container-fluid">
    <div class="container cat-list-container">

            <ul>
                <?php wp_list_categories( array(
                    'orderby'            => 'id',
                    'show_count'         => false,
                    'show_option_all'     => 'Show All',
                    'title_li' => false
                ) ); ?>
            </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

This created a button at the start of my list called: Show All.